# Jupyter file not rendering properly

Tags: github, jupyter

My final project has to be done in Jupyter file, and then shared on GitHub. My problem is that only I can see the Jupyter file in readable format because as soon as I try to share it either on GitHub or Watson Studio it changes to something unreadable. Even when I create the notebook on Watson Studio, it looks fine until I save it, because after save, I can't view it again in the "nice format" - it just looks unreadable again.

I'm trying to figure out my own problem and I noticed that if I delete markdown cells with the code:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alertsucess" style="margin-top: 5px">
<h1> Part 1 </h1>
</div>.
```

It actually renders fine at least for now - why would this be a problem if on my pc I can see it perfectly?

This is how I see it:

[image]

and this how looks on Watson Studio or GitHub:
https://github.com/elliebiessek/Coursera_Capstone/blob/master/Neighborhood%20Toronto%20-%20part%201.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Neighborhood Toronto - part 1.ipynb` change the following lines of code:

```
 "source": "<div class=\"alert alert-success alertsucess\" style=\"margin-top: 5px\">\n<h1> Part 1 </h1>\n</div>."
```

To

```
"source": "<div class=\"alert alert-success alertsucess\" style=\"margin-top: 5px\">\n<h1> Part 1 </h1>\n</div>"
```

Also from this line

```
"source": "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alertdanger\" style=\"margin-top: 5px\">\n<h1> Explanation notes </h1>\nPlease note that the instructions given to us are outdated, as after droping \"Not assigned\" Boroughs, the rest is automatically done. There was no need for the code to make changes to neighborhood as those changes are automatically there in wiki website itself. However, to make sure that I get full points I included the pointless codes nonetheless. \n</div>."
```

To

```
"source": "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alertdanger\" style=\"margin-top: 5px\">\n<h1> Explanation notes </h1>\nPlease note that the instructions given to us are outdated, as after droping \"Not assigned\" Boroughs, the rest is automatically done. There was no need for the code to make changes to neighborhood as those changes are automatically there in wiki website itself. However, to make sure that I get full points I included the pointless codes nonetheless. \n</div>"
```

In simple words remove the dots ( . ) after the closing div tags. Then the format will be fine.

Or you can simple follow these steps to edit it on Github:

1:

Go to Github repositories click on the `Neighborhood Toronto - part 1.ipynb`

2:

Click Edit this file.

3:

Simply remove the dot (.) and commit changes.

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you!

Comment: @EllieBiessek You are welcome, please accept it as answer if it was helpful.

Comment: How do I accept it as helpful? I clicked the arrow up but since I'm new it tells me I don't have enough reputation